# Cannot read property 'queryParams' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the query parameters from the url (using Angular 5):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-shop',
    templateUrl: './shop.component.html'
})

export class ShopComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        private sub: any;

        private keyword: string;

        this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.keyword = params['keyword'] || null;
        });

        console.log(this.keyword);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

I get the following error in the console log:

> shop.component.ts:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'queryParams' of undefined

Comment: Is your component inserted in a template with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` or directly with its own selector `<app-shop></app-shop>`? In order to get the route, you should use the `router-outlet` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that I've set the `private` variables inside the `ngOnInit()`, which was causing the error. Huh...!

Comment: Strange: the error said that `this.route` was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `this.sub =` from accessing to route. Also you can try to accees to query params via dot:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.keyword = params.keyword || null;
});
```